# nsuserdefault has key-values set how to delete it?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I have already tried to delete all the key-values pair when the app starts and again when i check keys these keys are saved in NSUserDefault. I have these preferences stored.

```
NSArray *keys = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys];
NSLog(@"all keys %@", keys);


keys (
    NSLanguages,
    AppleITunesStoreItemKinds,
    AppleLocale,
    AppleLanguages,
    NSInterfaceStyle
)
```

When I store new dynamic values to the NSUserDefaults, I want to select all the keys except these preferences.

Please help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you want to delete preferences, that don't belong to you?

Comment: I want to check whether values are inserted in NSUserDefaults. Without deleting these preferences how can I do? Please suggest.

Comment: If you test for an object, the dictionary will return nil if it is unset.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do what you're trying to do. Don't tamper with any of the keys added by Apple. Keep your own set of keys (preferably with prefixes on the names) and edit only those.

Generally you shouldn't delete keys unless there is some specific requirement in your app to do so. What you should do is to set default values for each of your keys when the app starts:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{... : ...}];
```

These defaults will be valid while the app is running but won't be saved. If you set anything using any of the `set...:forKey:` methods and `synchronize` then they will overwrite the defaults and be saved.

Comment: I want to save dynamic key-value pairs and I dont know key. How can I retrieve all the key-value pairs except the preferences..

Comment: How can you not know the key? Use a single key and store a dictionary where that dict contains your mystery items.

Comment: Can we select all keys except the prefrences.

Comment: If you prefix each of your keys then you can check during iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`- (NSDictionary *) dictionaryRepresentation`.  Using this method on the standard user defaults, you can get a list of all keys in the user defaults.  You can then use this to clear the user defaults:

```
    NSUserDefaults * defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary * dict = [defs dictionaryRepresentation];
    for (id key in dict) {
        [defs removeObjectForKey:key];
    }
    [defs synchronize];
```

**removeObjectForKey** -- that should give you the ability to remove a preference.

Comment: I have already tried this, it only delete the keys added not the preferences. I have key-value pair of only newly added items. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you tried this one [NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];

Comment: Preferences are not remove from the above code , when I check all keys stored in NSUserDefault there still exists : keys (
    NSLanguages,
    AppleITunesStoreItemKinds,
    AppleLocale,
    AppleLanguages,
    NSInterfaceStyle
). I have key-value pair where I dont know keys and my main problem is how do I access those keys??

Answer (score 0):

You can remove everything in `NSUserDefaults` associated with your app by calling this.

```
// remove entire user defaults
NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; // not sure if needed, but never hurts
```

This should give you a clean slate for saving information to user defaults.